# Wordpress make posts align accordingly

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, alignment

I am trying to `align` posts in `Wordpress` to align as example in the image attached. Currently if I use inline:block or float, the posts aren't exactly aligning the way I need with `css/html`. I am not sure what this is even called to search for help, Is there anyone who knows what this is called or how to accomplish this?

I have 2 columns and want them to still fill the screen regardless of the size of the post with no large white spaces in between.

Thanks

[image: Image example]

Comment: Search for "Masonry layout"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a WordPress template which offers "Masonry" grid.

> Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space.

You can have an example:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different template and a plugin maybe. most of new Wordpress template have been designed with bootstrap, LESS or SASS which are responsive and your Normal CSS code added to the css files will not change anything at all. Unless you directing change the template which is not recommanded if you are a begginer or use media queries "@media screen and (min-width: 480px)" depending on what your theme is using